# Why can't i pass map from jsp to Servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets, jstl, jsp-tags

I want to pass a `Map<String,Object>` from jsp page to servlet. I have tried with  `c:set value="${map} scope="request">` and also with scriplet `<%request.setAttribute("map",map)%>` but when i try to retrieve map from servlet it always gives null ?

Comment: is it the same request when you go from JSP to servlet?

Comment: How do you do that? How do you call your servlet from jsp page?

Comment: but you have set this map to request scope,and if it's a new request,map won't be available in second request,just for testing set it at some other scope,like session or context.

Comment: @Outofmemory: Right, But what is not possible? I just want to know, how does he go through jsp page to servlet class, by submit button, by dispatcher, or anything else.

Comment: @AliSepehri.Kh I am navigating from jsp to servlet via submit button

Comment: i know i can set parameters as hidden field ,but then at servlet sidea all i will get is request.getParameter/request.parametersMap..i dont want to loose Map while transferring from jsp to servlet

Comment: All i want is ---ServletA(Map)--pass using request.setAtrribute-->jspPage(get the same map)---send(submit) the same map to-->ServletB...i dont want to set it in session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using submit button to trigger your servlet class. When you press submit button a new `request` object is created and it will not contain your map object.

To resolve this problem you can use `session` object instead of `request` object.

**Note:** Same request object transfer through jsp page to servlet class when you used forward method through them. Pay attention that in your case that is not possible in normal way; because you want to get some info from user and submit button will send them to servlet.

Comment: is there any alternative , i dont want to use session object?

Comment: Usaually there is no need to do this, sending an object to client and get same object from client. You are doing something wrong.

Comment: thanks for helping me out . Is there any way ? i am not modifing anything in map , i just want to bypass it

Comment: @hpppy18: 1) Retrieve this Map object in your second servlet (maybe you are doing it again) 2) Use session object (same object for each user). The ways I know.

Comment: ..is this a good idea ..lets say user had done some  shopping and added some items in shop cart and did submit ,from  servlet side i will to pass the same shopped item object to client , and then what if client wants to add more items in it ...my whole point is setting data in session scope will get refelected for all users right , please correct me if my concept it wrong

Comment: @hpppy18: Yes, you are wrong. Each user has a separate object of `session`. In your case the `session` object is the exactly what you want. `context` object is shared between all of the users.

Comment: Thanks Ali Sepehri.kh . Now i have got fair idea :) thanks a lot again :)